# Why should I hash keys in the NearProtocol UnorderedMap?

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

In the Near NFT example, why are keys in the `account_gives_access` UnorderedMap hashed?
https://github.com/near-examples/NFT/blame/master/contracts/rust/src/lib.rs

```rust
pub struct NonFungibleTokenBasic {
    pub token_to_account: UnorderedMap<TokenId, AccountId>,
    pub account_gives_access: UnorderedMap<AccountIdHash, UnorderedSet<AccountIdHash>>, 
    pub owner_id: AccountId,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UnorderedMap` type uses a trie. An attacker could unbalance the trie by
repeatedly pushing keys onto the trie that push the depth of one side of the
trie deep. This would reduce performance of trie lookups on names beneath the
attacker's.

A mitigation to the attock is to store hashes of the keys. The hashes would be
equally distributed among possible values. The attacker could still perform the
attack, but generating specific hashes is hard, so some protocols say.

Another mitigation to the attack is to use a `LookupMap`, which uses an AVL
tree, which automatically rebalances its tree.

The attack isn't significantly threatening. The worst the attacker can do is
punish a small range of key values, by repeatedly paying the storage costs to
push an extremely limited range of key values farther down the trie. It therefore, probably
isn't worth paying the cost to hash the keys.

However, for trees that store a large number of keys, hashing keys, or a `LookupMap`, may still be
worth considering, as an unbalanced trie is very likely to result.

To recap, we reviewed the comparison of cost between:

- Hashing each key before storing and retreiving to an `UnorderedMap`
- Allowing the "attack" described above
- Using a `LookupMap` instead of an `UnorderedMap`

thanks @MikePurvis for explanation.

Comment: It's correct that the reason to hash keys is to avoid creating an unbalanced trie. But the `LookupMap` doesn't use a AVL tree. It's still using same mechanism to store keys, but without ability to iterate on the keys. The AVL Tree is called `TreeMap` but it's use-case is ordering keys instead of the balancing. It still uses a `LookupMap` internally. Another use case is to make account length predictable

Comment: @EvgenyKuzyakov Oh, interesting. Then my mental model is that none of the three map types, {Unordered,Tree,Lookup}Map do rebalancing. Is that correct?  Further, the AVL tree-based `TreeMap` is the "ordered version" of the `LookupMap`. Correct?

Comment: So `TreeMap` does rebalance based on keys. But it has extra overhead for doing it. You can see implementation here: https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/near-sdk/src/collections/tree_map.rs